# How to refactor neo4j cypher aggregation with implicit grouping keys

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am getting an implicit grouping keys deprecation warning (neo4j 4.4) when I run this:

```
 MATCH (c:Coin)-[d:MARKET_DOMINANCE]->(e) WHERE c.name = "Terra"  AND d.created > (date({timezone: 'America/New York'}) - duration("P30DT0H0M"))
   WITH c.name AS name, toString(d.created) AS timeline,d.dominance_rate_change AS drc, d.volume_24h_ratio AS vrc ORDER BY d.created  DESC 
 RETURN
          {
            coin: name, 
            timeline: COLLECT(timeline),
            dominanceHistory: COLLECT(drc),
            volumeRatioHistory: COLLECT(vrc)
          }
```

The warning suggest I might be able to refactor this with a WITH clause for each collection. I am trying to do this by adding a second WITH statement like this:

```
MATCH (c:Coin)-[d:MARKET_DOMINANCE]->(e) WHERE c.name = 'Terra' AND d.created > (date({timezone: 'America/New York'}) - duration("P30DT0H0M"))
      WITH c.name AS name, toString(d.created) AS timeline,d.dominance_rate_change AS drc, d.volume_24h_ratio AS vrc ORDER BY d.created  DESC 
      WITH name AS Name, COLLECT(timeline) AS Timeline, COLLECT(drc) AS DOMH, COLLECT(vrc) AS VOLC
      RETURN
               {
                 coin: Name, 
                 timeline: Timeline,
                 dominanceHistory: DOMH,
                 volumeRatioHistory: VOLC
               }`;
```

The warning went away but I need to know if there is a better method of refactoring the query for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have no other suggestion to refactor the query since it is straightforward. I would only suggest to see the difference if you remove "ORDER BY d.created  DESC" since doing a collect() on line3 will group the data according to name.  Do a comparison on the result with or without "ORDER BY d.created  DESC" found in line 2.

Comment: I need the ORDER BY....Thanks for the thought.